# FindThreads only works if either C or CXX language is enabled

Tags: c++, cmake, toolchain

I'm trying to build a portable gcc in order to allow others to compile using different systems.

I used `crosstool-ng` to cross compile `gcc-8.2` for `x86_64`, I built a static toolchain.

I created the following toolchain file:

```
#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "x86_64")
set(QAMF_ROOT "/opt/hyperserver-dev/x86_64-qamf")

set(COMPILER_ROOT "${QAMF_ROOT}")
set(COMPILER_PREFIX "x86_64-qamf-linux-gnu-")
set(C_COMPILER "gcc")
set(CXX_COMPILER "g++")

# specify the cross compile
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    ${COMPILER_ROOT}/bin/${COMPILER_PREFIX}${C_COMPILER} )
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  ${COMPILER_ROOT}/bin/${COMPILER_PREFIX}${CXX_COMPILER} )

# HyperServer sysroot path
set(HYPERSERVER_SYSROOT "${COMPILER_ROOT}/x86_64-qamf-linux-gnu/sysroot") 

# where is the target environment 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${HYPERSERVER_SYSROOT} )

# search for programs in the build host directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

On my host machine it works great and I can compile without any issue but when I moved the toolchain file on another machine I have problems. If I try to include Threads on my cmake I've the error below:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:54 (message):
  FindThreads only works if either C or CXX language is enabled
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

This is my CMakeFiles/txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
project(HelloWorld C CXX)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

Comment: It would be helpful explain why the downvote in order to improve the question.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post a [mcve] as required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's impossible to post that... I cannot ask to build a toolchain to test it... I'm hoping someone else had the same issue

Comment: _"Is impossible to post that.."_ Then you're ddomed with this place, sorry.

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one with this problem... and if I can find a solution this can be useful for others

Comment: Isn't the error message *self-explanating*? You need `project()` or `enable_language()` call before `find_package(Threads)` for make it work. It seems that currently you have no such call, as `find_package()` is called from the line 2, leaving the first line for `cmake_minimum_required()`. (And I guess that absence of your `CMakeLists.txt` has lead to downvotes and a closevote.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you explain better... I'm never had to specify that in `cmake`... I updated the question with my `CMakeFiles.txt`

Comment: I double checked and in all my projects I never specified the language without any issue...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```

**after**

```
project(HelloWorld C CXX)
```

This is what the error message tells: The `project()` call enables languages, so finding the Threads would succeed.

---

Normally, **all** `find_package` calls should come **after** the `project()` one.

Comment: I needed only ```project(HelloWorld)```, i.e. no C or CXX. CMake seemed to guess it was a CXX project somehow.

Comment: @Will: "CMake seemed to guess it was a CXX project somehow." - Without language arguments, CMake enables both C and CXX languages by default. In my answer I write `project(HelloWorld C CXX)` because exactly this line is contained in the question post. `project(HelloWorld)` is a synonym to that line.